# E-mail from specific domain not delivered to one of the cc: recipients on Exchange 2010

Tags: email, exchange-2010

we have a user on Exchange 2010 server who doesn't get email from one specific domain if her address is in cc: field. If she is a main recipient (To:) it goes through. We checked Exchange logs and it looks like our server doesn't even try to deliver it, it simply *ignores* her email address completely.

We did several tests:

- send email with her email address in cc: field from another domain, succeeded
- send email with her email address in to: field from another domain, succeeded
- send email with her email address in to: field from affected domain, succeeded
- turn off all email rules
- check via webmail

We also turned off firewall, antispam and antivirus for SMTP rule.

Does anyone have any idea what could be an issue here?

Thanks

Comment: If she have set any filtering, remove that all filters. Probably filtering may the reason for dropping that mail.

Comment: No filters here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by incorrect settings on the senders server. They have had distribution lists on Exchange which replaced original recipients address with incorrect one.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour can be done using a transport rule.

Exchange Management Console, Microsoft Exchange On-Premises, Organization Configuration, Hub Transport, Transport Rules tab.

Examine the rules and see if any seem applicable. If one seems like it might be causing the behaviour then right-click it and choose Disable Rule and retest sending the mail.

Additionally, run a Message Tracking session with a start time of a few minutes before one of the test emails and see if that gives more information about where the message is going.